# Formated print opening hours (string) in php

Tags: php, printf, string-formatting

In C there is formatted print, which allows formatted printing of numbers - aligning them. Is something similar possible in PHP with strings?

I have 2 strings `$open_time`, `$close_time`. For example `$open_time="12:00"`, `$close_time="23:00"`.

**desired output**

```
12:00 - 23:00
 7:00 - 20:00
12:30 -  1:00
 5:00 -  6:00
```

**output with echo**

```
12:00 - 23:00
7:00 - 20:00
12:30 - 1:00
5:00 - 6:00
```

See that 12:00 are 5 characters, 7:00 are 4 characters? I need to add a space.
Is there a function in PHP which will print it with mask like in C (not sure if this is even possible in C)

```
some_print("string_5_charactersSPACE-SPACEstring_5_characters", $open_time,$close_time);
```

where SPACE mean space: `"%string_5_characters - %string_5_characters"`.

My simple solution is check if the string has 5 chars and if not I will just concatenate it with a space to get 5 chars ... But I'm curious if its possible to do it just by one function like it was possible with printing numbers in C.

Comment: @MackieeE thats what I wrote thats my "simple solution" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [sprintf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), take a look at [printf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) too.

Comment: Yeah printf("%5s - %5s\n",$opening_time, $close_time); Do what I want :)

Comment: Cool, I would have provided an example, but it isn't easy on an ipad :)